# Camel 3 Custom Endpoint Category

Tags: apache-camel

Hy,

I'm currently updating my project from Camel 2 to 3.
I have created a custom component with different endpoints and consumers/producers.
In the documentation of these endpoints I use labels to group them:
`@UriEndpoint(label = "ourServerProduct,delivery,upload,download")`
`@UriEndpoint(label = "ourServerProduct,administration,user")`

Using "label" was deprecated in Camel 3 so I tried to migrate it to "category".
The problem here is that "category" is an Array of the enum `Category`, which has a lot of predefined values, but I need to use custom values as these endpoints are used to talk to our server product.

As enums can not be extended in java, how could I create custom categories using this new documentation type.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, at this moment you have to choose on of the enums, or use the old deprecated label.

But it would be good to add `Cateogory.CUSTOM`. You are welcome to create a JIRA and provide a PR if you want as well.